# Can get the NETBIOS status of an IP address but cannot lookup the corresponding name

Tags: macos, netbios

I have tried on my macOS to lookup the NETBIOS name of my workstation. I find out that I can get the status of NETBIOS name corresponding to the private IP of my workstation using `smbutil status`. However, I cannot resolve the name I obtained using `smbutil lookup`.

```bash
$ smbutil status 10.245.92.223
Using IP address of 10.245.92.223: 10.245.92.223
Workgroup: WORKGROUP
Server: CLIMATE

$ smbutil lookup CLIMATE
smbutil: unable to resolve CLIMATE: No route to host
```

[smbutil results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM6dj.png)

I have also tried `nmblookup` command in another workstation and it got the same scenario. Is there anything else I need to check so that I can connect to my workstation using the NETBIOS name (instead of using the private IP)?

Comment: Do you specifically need NetBIOS instead of Apple's standard Bonjour/mDNS?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1359738/how-are-names-resolved-on-modern-local-networks & ironically https://superuser.com/questions/364687/how-to-resolve-netbios-names-on-mac-os-x